# How extract text from epub in Python (from an url source)

Tags: python, extract, epub

I want to extract the content from an epub, but I don't know how to do that from an url source. My code is like this for now: ([ebooklib](https://pypi.org/project/EbookLib/))

```
import urllib.request
import ebooklib
from ebooklib import epub


myurl = "https://diegooli.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Cabana.epub"

with urllib.request.urlopen(myurl) as url:
    s = url.read()

book = epub.read_epub(s)

for image in book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_IMAGE):
    print(image)
```

error, obviously:

```
    AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Can anyone give me a light?

Comment: Why would that error be obvious?

Comment: because I am aware that I am doing something very wrong =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the epub file first then open the file using the ebook library

- Use **urllib** to download the ebook
- Use **ebooklib** to open the ebook and get the images

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
import ebooklib
from ebooklib import epub

myurl = "https://diegooli.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Cabana.epub"

with urllib.request.urlopen(myurl) as url:
    s = url.read()
    
with open(r"c:\tmp\test.epub", "wb") as f:
    f.write(s)

book = epub.read_epub(r"c:\tmp\test.epub")

for image in book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_IMAGE):
    print(image)
```